# how to get twitter analytics using twitter gem rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, twitter-gem

I want to get twitter analytics for tweets I posted using twitter gem in my ruby on rails application. Is there any possibility to achieve this ? I want to show tweet impression on my application,please let me know if there is any possible way .

Answer (score 1):

You can pull engagement data for your account as a whole. On a per-tweet basis you can pull in a favorites count as well as a retweet count. Here is an example the latter:

First define your client like so:

```
client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = Devise.omniauth_configs[:twitter].strategy.consumer_key
    config.consumer_secret     = Devise.omniauth_configs[:twitter].strategy.consumer_secret
    config.access_token        = self.identities.find_by(provider: :twitter).token
    config.access_token_secret = self.identities.find_by(provider: :twitter).token_secret
end
```

Now define the API endpoint you want to pull data from along with an array of tweet ids you want to get data on:

```
path = "1.1/statuses/lookup.json"
ids = ['1234567890','56324931407']
```

Now call the API and do something with the response:

```
response = Twitter::REST::Request.new(client, 'get', path, {id: ids, map: true}).perform
```

The result you get back will be a JSON hash where the keys are the post ids. Calling `map: true` in the options hash tells the API to include missing post keys with a `null` value, rather than excluding them from the response. You can read more in the docs on the [Twitter::REST::Request](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Request) class.

Note that with the `Twitter::REST::Request` class you can specify any `path` and/or `method` from the API.

If you want to calculate engagement data for your account, you will have to pull in a large batch of tweets (say 100) and then parse the response and calculate the rate yourself, as Twitter doesn't offer that data through the API in a prepackaged way. [This Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Twitter-API/How-can-I-access-tweet-engagement-activity-details-via-the-API) goes into more detail on how you can calculate the engagement rate yourself.

As for pulling impression data, that is not currently possible through the public API. [See this discussion for more details.](https://twittercommunity.com/t/rest-api-support-for-impressions-data/13169/19)